# Rectangle is not moving if i set the x y from another class.

Tags: java, swing

Alright, so I got two classes here, the main and the keylistener class which i use to pass keyboard inputs to the main class.

```
    import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final static int WIDTH = 240;
    private final static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    private final static int SCALE = 2;
    private String TITLE = "Game";

    private boolean running = false;

    private Thread thread;

    Random r = new Random();

    ArrayList<Point> snakePart = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Point head;

    KeyHandle keyhandle;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        init();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);

        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);



        start();

    }

    public void init() {
        head = new Point(0,0);
        addKeyListener(new KeyHandle());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        final double ticks = 60.0;
        long initTime = System.nanoTime();
        double ns = 1000000000 / ticks;
        double delta = 0;

        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;

        while (running) {
            long nowTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (nowTime - initTime) / ns;
            initTime = nowTime;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;

            }

            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("Ticks: " + updates + " Frames: " + frames);
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }

        stop();

    }



    public void tick() {



    }



    public void render() {

        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(head.x, head.y, 10, 10);



        bs.show();
        g.dispose();

    }

    private synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;

        running = false;

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(1);
    }


}
```

and then i've got the keylistener class which looks like this

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandle implements KeyListener {

    Game game;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){


        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            game.head.y += 10;


        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){

        } 

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){

        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){

        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){

        } 

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Now the problem appears when I try to edit the "head" y and x values as seen in the second class.

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            game.head.y += 10;
```

What am I doing wrong here and is there a better way to pass and set x and y values more efficiently.

Comment: Where does `game` come from in your KeyListener?

Comment: game is the main class

Comment: I'm talking about the variable, not the class.

Comment: The only way  I can access head.y is through game

Comment: You're not passing over anything. `Game game` is null and your `game.head.y += 10;` should throw a NPE.

Comment: So i use Game game to get access to the head or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you suggest a better option ?

Comment: I thought that if i use Game game i would be able to pass over the methods and variables to other classes

Comment: You have to construct the `Game` though. Right now it's just a null object that's reserving memory for the object to be created. And if you want it to have an impact on the `Game` you see, it should be given to the listener.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: General advice: Before getting into more difficult things like using a `BufferStrategy` in a `Canvas` and using a `Thread`, I'd recommend working out how to do rendering in a `JPanel` by overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method and getting a Swing `Timer` to call `repaint()`. As it is, you are trying to do advanced rendering when you do not have a good grasp of the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Your KeyHandle class contains a reference to a Game but no intantiation of game. Instead of creating `new Game()` in your main method and dropping the instance on the floor, allocate that instance to the reference contained in KeyHandle.

`keyhandle.game = new Game();`